# How to automatic make-up the divs in parent div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a parent div and child divs with different width and height. How can I float the parent div with child's max effective without loss a space by absolute positioned elements.

The example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KSbjT

What kind of direction do I need to dig?

HTML

```
<div class="parent" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000; background: red; position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; background: blue;"></div>  
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000; background: green;"></div> 
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; background: yellow;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; background: aqua; position: absolute; top: 200px"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What will be the preference for the fill, top-down ? left-right ?

Comment: Well this would be a quite complicated algoritm, but my first start would be getting all the axis (x,y) of the child divs, and slice all my parent div with the possibilities, for each of those spaces I would scan (left-right) if there is a div inside it, if not I would append its "area" until it hits another div (right) or the edge of the parent div (right) and go one space down to begin the process of appending the area until I hit another right barrier or the bounds of the previous scan.

Comment: yes, my thoughts go in the same direction)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're asking but i THINK you might need to change your absolute positioned divs to relatively positioned so if you move the parent, all relatives will move relative to it.

Comment: firstly, i think all child divs must be absolute positioned) i dont know what next)

Comment: Ok what is it that you wish to happen? What do you want the parent div or the child divs to do?

Comment: child divs must fill the parent max effective without any loss the space

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want?

Comment: just try to imagine how to do that)

Answer (score 0):

When using float and positioning of divs corresponding to others then you want to look at

```
position: relative;
```

That is, the divs are not controlled by a fixed position on the screen, instead it's position corresponding to the div next to it.

I recommend that you separate your html and css so that your html does not contain any style attributes, instead you create more html classes/ids that you control with your css, something like this would be much prettier and easier to read:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="blueGuy"></div>  
    <div id="greenGuy"></div> 
    <div id="yellowGuy"></div>
    <div id="aquaGuy"></div>
</div>
```

Wherea, for example, blueGuy would look like this

```
#blueGuy
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: blue;
}
```

Even better would be to classify look that you can reuse be adding it into classes, for example with the borders and the width/height.